# Datapager for listview always goes to page 1 of results

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datapager

I am using a Listview and Datapager control. But when I refresh the page it always set the datapager to page 1. I want that it should be in the same page after refreshing. For example I want the same functionality as stackoverflow is having like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datapager. How to do this can any one help.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying a value for the `QueryStringField` parameter in your DataPager:

```
<asp:DataPager ... QueryStringField="page">
```

This will convert all paging controls for that DataPager into hyperlinks, and the page number will be passed in the URL query string (in the example above, the URL will look like e.g., "http://www.example.com/search.aspx?query=xyz**&page=2**").

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager.querystringfield%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for more information.